How to ignore a field from a nested data structure when testing with unittest?
I am trying to test the rotate_left operation of a Red-Black Tree. But I keep receiving RecursionError. Here is my WIP implementation:
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 0
    BLACK = 1

@dataclass
class Node(Generic[T]):
    color: Color
    value: T
    parent: Optional['Node[T]'] = None
    left: Optional['Node[T]'] = None
    right: Optional['Node[T]'] = None

@dataclass
class RedBlackTree(Generic[T]):
    root: Node

    def rotate_left(self, x: Node[T]):
        y = x.right
        x.right = y.left
        if y.left != None:
            y.left.parent = x

        y.parent = x.parent
        if x.parent == None:
            self.root = y
        elif x == x.parent.left:
            x.parent.left = y
        else: 
            x.parent.right = y
        y.left = x
        x.parent = y

Here is my test case:
import pprint
import unittest
from src.red_black_tree import RedBlackTree, Node, Color

class TestRedBlackTreeMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_left_rotation(self):
      node4 = Node(Color.BLACK, value=15, left=None, right=None)
      node2 = Node(Color.BLACK, value=2, left=None, right=None)
      node3 = Node(Color.RED, value=12, left=None, right=node4)
      node1 = Node(color=Color.RED, parent=None, left=node2, right=node3, value=10)
      node4.parent = node3
      node3.parent = node1
      node2.parent = node1
      tree = RedBlackTree(root=node1)

      tree.rotate_left(node1)

      expected_node4 = Node(Color.BLACK, value=2, left=None, right=None)
      expected_node3 = Node(color=Color.RED, left=node2, value=10)
      expected_node2 = Node(Color.BLACK, value=15, left=None, right=None)
      expected_node1 = Node(Color.RED, value= 12, parent=None, right=expected_node2, left=expected_node3)
      expected_node2.parent = expected_node1
      expected_node3.parent = expected_node1
      expected_node4.parent = expected_node3
      expected_tree = RedBlackTree(root=expected_node1)

      self.assertEqual(tree.root.value, expected_tree.root.value)
      self.assertEqual(tree.root.left.value, expected_tree.root.left.value)
      self.assertEqual(tree.root.right.value, expected_tree.root.right.value)
      self.assertEqual(tree.root.left.left.value, expected_tree.root.left.left.value)
      self.assertEqual(tree, expected_tree)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

I suspect that doing self.assertEqual(tree, expected_tree) blows the stack because of the parent attribute. So i would like to know if its possible to make unittest ignore this attribute or if there is a more adequate method for this situation.

Rather than construct an expected tree, why not just verify that the red-black invariants on tree are maintained after rotate_left is applied?

That's sounds more reasonable, thank you for the suggestion!

I think assertEqual is limited to values and core data types (see here). Your tree class is not represented in such as fashion, from what I can tell.
If checking specific nodes is not enough, you probably need to find a way to iterate through the entire tree. You can then iterate both trees and compare the elements pairwise. Alternatively you can use the iteration to make a representation of the tree. You write all necessary values for a comparison into a new data type (like a list) that is compatible with assertEqual. Then you can compare the two tree representations.
